# Building Hours in a Foreign Country

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations

I currently hold my Commercial Certificate with Instrument. Currently all FAA. Attended ATP Flight School in Texas. I was born in Nicaragua so I can legally work there. I was offered a job to work for a local airline called La Costeña. I would love to take that opportunity and fly in my home country but I’m confused on how this will all work. So I want to work towards my 1500hrs to eventually apply for Envoy then of course to AA through their flow through agreement. So here it is, I will be a First Officer. As far as logging my time, I see that Envoy requires 250hrs fixed wing PIC time and 100hrs of Cross country PIC within the 1500hr requirement. My question is, will I be able to log PIC time as a FO when I’m the sole manipulator of the controls? I know that legally speaking, according to the FAA, I could. But any idea on how Envoy views it? TIA

Comment: Welcome to A.S.E.! Will the flight time acquired in Nicaragua be in an airplane that meets the requirements of FAR 61.51 (j)? If so, for FAA flight time you can "log" PIC time when you are sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which you are rated (not limited to SIC privileges). Will you be "rated" in the aircraft that you will be flying as an FO, assuming that the requirements of 61.51(j) are met? What type of airplane will you be flying in Nicaragua?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Yes the aircraft does meet the requirements under 61.51(j)(2) since they fall under ICAO. I will be starting off on the Cessna Caravans and potentially later be trained on their ATR 42. Although the caravan is single pilot, they do have an agreement in place for FO’s to be able to log time as well. Not sure what they call this agreement in Nicaragua. Although I can log PIC time as an FO, do you know how some airlines view this? Do airlines look for or prefer Captain PIC time or does it matter much? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I do not know exactly how Envoy would look at the flight time logged as PIC while you were actually flying as an SIC on a single-pilot airplane.  Once you have your U.S. ATP  and are applying to Envoy I'm assuming that the characteristics of your total flight time would be weighed and valued accordingly.  In my opinion, writing a letter to Envoy (e.g., the Director of Operations) and explaining your question regarding the type of flight time that you have acquired might result in a clearer answer to your question.  Good luck!